# How to edit the profile image and store the changes permanently? When changes the profile image, store it in Firebase Firestore at the same time?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-image-picker

I still new in learning flutter. Currently, I am trying to create the profile page but I encountered some issues with saving the selected image that chosen from the image picker. How can I save the changes of profile image permanently after I choose the image from the gallery because when I move other page and back to the profile page, the picture that changed will back to the default Image.asset('img/profile2.png',fit: BoxFit.cover). Another issue is how can I store the profile image into Firebase Firestore and track back the profile image if exist? Please help me guys, appreciate those help, thank you.

**Code:**

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print, unused_local_variable
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/models/empty_content_animation_view.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/models/image_store.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/utils.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/widgets/profile_text_box.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  // current user
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    // pick image from device gallery
    final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? _file = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    if (_file != null) {
      return await _file.readAsBytes();
    }
    print('No Images Selected');
  }

  // edit field
  Future<void> editField(String field) async {
    String newName = '';
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: Text(
          'Edit $field',
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        content: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter new $field',
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            newName = value;
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          // cancel button
          TextButton(
            child: const Text(
              'Cancel',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          // save button
          TextButton(
            child: const Text(
              'Save',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(newName),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    // update profile details in Firebase Firestore
    if (newName.trim().isNotEmpty) {
      // only update if there is something in the textfield
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(currentUser.email)
          .update({field: newName});
    }
  }

  // change image
  Uint8List? _image;
  void selectImage() async {
    Uint8List img = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = img;
    });
  }

  File? image;

  Future takeImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    final imageTemp = File(image!.path);

    setState(() {
      this.image = imageTemp;
    });
  }

  Future<void> saveImage() async {
    String file;
    String resp = await StoreData().saveData(file: _image!);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Profile Page'),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(153, 121, 133, 248),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Users')
              .doc(currentUser.email)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final userData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  // imageProfile(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  _image != null
                      ? CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                        )
                      : CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'img/profile2.png',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                  IconButton(
                    alignment: const Alignment(0.2, -5),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                    tooltip: 'Edit',
                    onPressed: () {
                      selectImage();
                      print('Edit Image');
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_rounded),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    currentUser.email!,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  // user details
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'My Details',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // username
                  ProfileTextBox(
                    text: userData['username'],
                    sectionName: 'username',
                    onPressed: () => editField('username'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed: saveImage,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
                    label: const Text('Save'),
                  )
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              Get.snackbar(
                'Error',
                'Error${snapshot.error}',
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                colorText: Colors.black,
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              );
            }
            return const EmptyContentsAnimationView();
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

**Image:**

[image: Profile Page]